# Can I import a component in Vue.js with path based on prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am using the Material design Icons library for Vue.js.
This library contains a folder and every icon is a single file component in that folder.

I have another component, *ToolbarButton*, that has a prop *Icon* and I want to import component with name same as the passed prop.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <button>
        <MyIcon></MyIcon>
    </button>
</template>

<script>

import MyIcon from `icons/${icon}.vue`
export default {
    name: 'ToolbarButton',
    props: ['icon']
    components: {
        MyIcon
    }
}
</script>
```

This code throws an error Parsing *error: Unexpected token `*
Using 'icons/' + icon + '.vue' doesn't help.
Is there any way to do that?
I have been searching for over an hour but didn't find any solution.
Somebody recommended importing all of the components because the unused ones will go away when compiling, but that doesn't sound like the right way to do that.

Comment: Did you try dynamic imports? The problem here is, that the import is done before the icon property has any value. Dynamic imports work like `MyComponent = defineAsyncComponent(async () => import(\`icons/${icon}.vue\`))`. You need to define the component inside your setup function for instance and then use `<component :is="MyComponent" />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [async components](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#async-components) as follows :

```html
<template>
  <MyIcon />
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(["icon"]);
const MyIcon = defineAsyncComponent(function () {
  return import(`./icons/Icon${props.icon}.vue`);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me : (
Can you please take a look at this live CodeSandbox?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/prod-violet-upo3ur?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FButtonWithIcon.vue)

Thank you!

Comment: @ŠtěpánŽák please check my edited answer, the issue that you cannot access `this`

Answer (score 0):

1. It can be the backticks (`). In JS, backticks are used to define template literals, which allow for easier string interpolation and multiline strings. However, template literals are not supported in all browsers and versions of JavaScript

```js
import MyIcon from `icons/${icon}.vue` // incorrect - uses backticks
import MyIcon from 'icons/' + icon + '.vue' // incorrect - uses concatenation
import MyIcon from 'icons/' + icon // correct - uses concatenation with file extension
import MyIcon from `icons/${icon}` // correct - uses template literals with curly braces
import MyIcon from `icons/${icon}.vue`.default // correct - uses template literals with curly braces and .default
```

2. My suggestion is also using dynamic import. Its kind a optimises way and It helps to reduce bundle size

```js
export default {
  name: 'ToolbarButton',
  props: ['icon'],
  components: {
    MyIcon: () => import(`icons/${this.icon}.vue`)
  }
}
```